# orginal image resolution estimate

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking for an image analyzing algorithm that estimates the "original" resolution of a picture after is has been scaled up.

I understand the result would depend a lot on image motive, focus, noise and post effects, but getting a rough estimate of a minimum size image that has the same information content would be quite interesting.

Is there something like this out there already, maybe even an existing tool/plugin?

Comment: I was going to suggest doing a FFT and looking for the dropoff at the top to determine the original Nyquist frequency, but depending on the scaling algorithm there could be artifacts up there. Probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming this is a practical problem, as opposed to a theoretical question).

Have you looked at metadata? A lot of image processing software leaves the EXIF headers untouched, or appends helpful information to them...